# Get part of class name from parent and apply to child JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, pattern-matching

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<tr class="wiring_details_6-48">
    <td colspan="2"> Wire Type:
        <select name="select_wire_6" onchange="Estimate.select_wire( 6, this.value, 0 );">
            <option value="" selected="">Select wire..</option>
            <option value="1">14/2</option>
            <option value="2">14/4</option>
            <option value="3">16/4</option>
            <option value="4">16/2</option>
            <option value="5">RG6</option>
            <option value="6">CAT5</option>
            <option value="7">RG59</option>
            <option value="8">LVT</option>
            <option value="9">CAT6</option>
            <option value="10">HDMI</option>
            <option value="11">Shielded CAT6</option>
        </select> </td>
    <td colspan="2">Length:
        <input type="text" class="id_wire_length_6" name="wire_length_6" value="0"></td>
    <td colspan="2">Retail Price:
        <input type="text" class="id_wire_retail_6" name="wire_retail_6" value="0"> </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="hidden" id="wire_id_6" name="wire_id_6" value="0"> </td>
</tr>
```

I want to make sure that `input` - `id_wire_length` and `id_wire_retail` are related to their parent `tr` this can be proven due to the `part-id` which is in this example the number `6` in `wiring_details` and in `id_wire_length` and `id_wire_retail`.

The **JS** that I have is:

```
$('input[class^="id_wire_retail"]').each(function() {
    parts_cents_total += (Money.dollars_to_cents($(this).val()) * $('input[class^="id_wire_length"]').val());
});
```

The above matches the `id_wire_detail` part as well as the `id_wire_length` - but how do I make sure that it is the one related to its parent,

### So I guess it comes down to this:

How do I get the parent `tr`'s part number (6) and then make sure that the above JS matches only input elements with the `tr`'s part number in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$('input[class^="id_wire_length"]').val()
```

...try this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[class^="id_wire_length"]').val()
```

This will ensure that the value you're selecting is the one "inside" the same `<tr>`. Assuming the HTML structure is as you've posted above, you shouldn't have to worry about matching by part number.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as there are other `tr` elements with different part `id`'s and they all use the same functions...